# Comparing two shuffling methods

Tags: java, reinventing-the-wheel, comparative-review, collections, shuffle

I'm trying to randomly shuffle an collection of integers within a `List` and I have came up with two shuffling method that does the job. However, I'm not sure which one works better. Does any one have any comments or suggestions?

```
public class TheCollectionInterface {

    public static <E> void swap(List<E> list1, int i, int j){
        E temp = list1.get(i);
        list1.set(i, list1.get(j));
        list1.set(j, temp);
    }

//alternative version    
//    public static void shuffling(List<?> list, Random rnd){
//        for(int i = list.size(); i >= 1; i--){
//            swap(list, i - 1, rnd.nextInt(i));
//        }
//    }


    public static <E> void shuffling(List<E> list1, Random rnd){
        for(int i = list1.size(); i >= 1; i--){
            swap(list1, i - 1, rnd.nextInt(list1.size()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> li2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

        Random r1 = new Random();

        TheCollectionInterface.shuffling(li2, r1);

        System.out.println(li2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider [`Collections.shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))?

Comment: yes, that's another alternative, but I just want to come up with a shuffling method myself, practice with the logic :)

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm doesn't have simple uniform distribution over `!n`. Your alternative do has it, is actually a known algorithm named [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment! Could you please explain in a bit more detail why my algorithm doesn't have simple uniform distribution over !n?